# Unable to get download progress with retrofit coroutines API call

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

As we know Kotlin coroutine suspended block will be suspended until the job is done.

I mas trying to download a file using an API with coroutine supported retrofit call, which is an suspended call.Here my problem is I want to show progress of download from 0% to 100%.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please take a look at this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question by adding what you have tried so far.

Comment: First of all you cannot show the progress if you don't have such data. A call to an API endpoint cannot be made as progress, since that depends on the size of the payload and transfer speed.

Comment: @Daniel It is a File download API. size will be more than 5MB.